stationary distribution of random walk, and its mixing time if two different walk matrices are sampled with some probability
Let's say I have some state vector $\mathbf{s}$, and two random walk matrices $\mathbf{M}_1$ and $\mathbf{M}_2$, see here: https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F09/scribe-notes/lec15.pdf for background information on random walk and Markov chains. Now let's say the stationary distribution of $\mathbf{M}_1$ is: $\mathbf{s}^*_1 = \mathbf{s}^{\intercal} \mathbf{M}^n$, and similarly: $\mathbf{s}^*_2 = \mathbf{s}^{\intercal} \mathbf{M}^n$, where $n$ refers to $n$ steps of applying the walk matrix.
Now say I set up an experiment whereby $\mathbf{M}_1$ is chose with probability $p$, and $\mathbf{M}_2$ is chosen with probability $1-p$. Then

what is the stationary distribution of this new random walk:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{s}^* = \mathbf{s}^{\intercal} (\mathbf{M}_i \circ \mathbf{M}_i \circ ... \circ \mathbf{M}_i), \;\; i \in \{1,2\},
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{M}_i$ is sampled with probability $p$ for $i=1$ and $1-p$ for $i=2$.

What is the mixing time of this new random walk?

and finally let's say we generalize this a setting whereby $k$ different walk matrices are selected with probability $p_1, p_2, ... p_k$. What is the stationary distribution and the mixing time here?


